# Return type for __init__ in docstrings

Tags: python, python-2.7, docstring

I've recently started using PyCharm and it support type hinting for Python 2.x using docstrings which I'd like to start using.
What should be the `:return:` value for the `__init__` method of a class `Foo`?
I can't find an answer to wether it should be `Foo`, `None`, nothing, or remove the attribute that PyCharm is creating in the docstring template for me?

Comment: `__init__` shouldn't return anything and is unlikely to ever get assigned, so it doesn't matter what you put. If your method doesn't `return`, you can remove the `:return:` entry, as it will always be `None`. In fact I usually document the class itself rather than `__init__`, which generally doesn't need its own docstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The answer to the question credit should go to @ppperry)

Because all `__init__` methods return `None`, no docstrings about return type are required.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method should return `None`.  If you try to return anything else, Python will raise an error when the object is instantiated.  Note: If you don't explicitly tell Python what a function should return, it returns None.  Because of this, I have never needed to use the return statement in any of my `__init__` methods.

Comment: I understand that, my question is regarding the *docstring* for the `__init__` method, not the return value itself.

Comment: @JosepValls Thus, because all `__init__` methods return `None`, no docss about return type are required.